# If $f$ is a function of moderate decrease then $\delta \int f(\delta x) dx = \int f(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

A function of moderate decrease is a map from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{C}$ such that there exists $A \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \ |f(x)| \lt \frac{A}{1 + |x|^{1+\epsilon}}$.  Let $\epsilon$ be fixed, then such functions form a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ called $\mathcal{M}_{\epsilon}(\mathbb{R})$.  Improper integrals are well-defined for such functions.  I want to prove the property called "Scaling under dilations":

For any $\delta \gt 0$,
$$
\delta \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\delta x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx
$$

My problem is showing that $f(\delta$x) is in $\mathcal{M}_{\epsilon}(\mathbb{R})$.  Or do we have to?  I.e. could we just show that the improper integral on the left is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to show that $x \mapsto f(\delta x)$ belongs to $\mathcal{M}_\varepsilon(\mathbb{R})$, but it's not hard. If $\lvert \delta\rvert \geqslant 1$, then

$$\lvert f(\delta x)\rvert \leqslant \frac{A}{1 + \lvert \delta x\rvert^{1+\varepsilon}} \leqslant \frac{A}{1+\lvert x\rvert^{1+\varepsilon}},$$

and if $0 < \lvert \delta\rvert < 1$, then

$$\lvert f(\delta x)\rvert \leqslant \frac{A}{1 + \lvert \delta x\rvert^{1+\varepsilon}} \leqslant \frac{A}{\lvert\delta\rvert^{1+\varepsilon}+\lvert \delta x\rvert^{1+\varepsilon}} = \frac{A\cdot \lvert \delta\rvert^{-(1+\varepsilon)}}{1 + \lvert x\rvert^{1+\varepsilon}},$$

so in either case, $x \mapsto f(\delta x)$ belongs to $\mathcal{M}_\varepsilon(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: How do you get the second inequality in your second block of math.  The denominator gets bigger possibly, with $\delta \gt 1$.  So you haven't proven that it's in $M_e(R)$.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: he's assuming $0<|\delta|<1$ for the second pair of inequalites, so $|\delta|^{1+\epsilon}<1$.

Comment: Can't do that though, I specified $\delta \gt 0$.

Comment: @EnjoysMath So ignore the absolute modulus then. In the first block I treat $\delta \geqslant 1$, and in the second $0 < \delta < 1$.

Comment: Oh, nevermind.  I'm stoned.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a continuity requirement on $f$? Then use the change of variables formula, which guarantees that $\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}f(x)=\int_{a}^bf(\phi(u))\phi'(u)du$ for continuiously differentiable $\phi$.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer: For some reason I thought there was an arbitrary, possibly atomic measure in the integral. Thanks.